# <input type="radio"> does not line up with <text></text> behind it

Tags: html, css, text, radio-button, html-input

My 
`<input type="radio">`

in my form does not line up with my 
`<text></text>`

behind it.

[Example of my form](https://deepmotions.github.io/submission.html)

Comment: not clear where you have this text, moreover <text> in not an HTML tag but an SVG tag

Comment: *a* `does not line up with` *b*: using which viewer/browser?

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't use `<text>`, as DaFois said. Use `<label>` instead

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio">
  Label Text
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

below is working fine have look , to make it work you have to wrap you radio button in span, than wrap span and text div.

Real magic is you put your input control in span and set style sheet of span to make content center. that will do work for you.

```
.center {
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display:inline;
}

<div>
    <span class="center">
       <input type="radio">
    </sapn> text of radio
</div>
```

Working demo at jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hfu1zaxg/1/

Comment: You should describe what you changed and why instead of just giving code.

Comment: @csm_dev - done , actully its very easy to understna that y no much information given by me but now done